# Loop through an array of map objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion

everybody.
I have an Array of Map Objects, these map objects simple has `url: "string", css: "string", childCSS: []` properties.
I want to do this objects inside their childCSS properties. What should i use? This recursion could have infinite numbers of childs, childs and childs.
What do think about this?
I have this array, for example:

```
[
    {
        url: "http://example.com/1.css",
        css: "... *css for 1.css*",
        childCSS: [
            "http://example.com/1-1.css",
            "http://example.com/1-2.css"
        ]
    },
    {
        url: "http://example.com/1-1.css",
        css: "... *css for 1-1.css*",
        childCSS: [
            "http://example.com/1-1-1.css"
        ]
    },
    {
        url: "http://example.com/1-2.css",
        css: "... *css for 1-2.css*",
        childCSS: []
    },
    {
        url: "http://example.com/1-1-1.css",
        css: "... *css for 1-1-1.css*",
        childCSS: [
            "http://example.com/1-1-1-1.css"
        ]
    },
    {
        url: "http://example.com/1-1-1-1.css",
        css: "... *css for 1-1-1-1.css*",
        childCSS: []
    }
    .
    .
    .
],
```

I want to do this Array, like this:
Childs, inside of their childs:

```
[
    {
        url: "http://example.com/1.css",
        css: "... *css for 1.css*",
        childCSS: [
            {
                url: "http://example.com/1-1.css",
                css: "... *css for 1-1.css*",
                childCSS: [
                    {
                        url: "http://example.com/1-1-1.css",
                        css: "... *css for 1-1-1.css*",
                        childCSS: [
                            {
                                url: "http://example.com/1-1-1-1.css",
                                css: "... *css for 1-1-1-1.css*",
                                childCSS: []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                url: "http://example.com/1-2.css",
                css: "... *css for 1-2.css*",
                childCSS: []
            }
        ]
    },
    .
    .
    .
]
```

Thanks for everything. Have good day, all!

Comment: "This recursion could have infinite numbers of childs". Recursion is the magic word there, but what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried recursive functions, loops inside loop but they only make 2 steps away, not make all of the childrens. How can I describe a unlimited childs maker algorithms for this problem, i dont know :/

Comment: You can do it by using...recursive functions and/or single level loops.

Comment: Is there any example for this solution?

Comment: `var obj = /* your data structure*/; while (obj.childCSS.length > 0) { obj = obj.childCSS[0] }` it's not exactly right but it's in general how you can traverse nested objects using a single loop. The recursive traverse would be `function traverse(obj) { if (obj.childCSS.length > 0) traverse(obj.childCSS[0]) }`. You can use a modified version of this to walk the array and children of each, then do whatever you want with each thing you encounter, like add them to an array

Answer (score 1):

you don't need no recursion here, you can do that by iterating twice over your data:

```js
let data = [
    {
        url: "http://example.com/1.css",
        css: "... *css for 1.css*",
        childCSS: [
            "http://example.com/1-1.css",
            "http://example.com/1-2.css"
        ]
    },
    {
        url: "http://example.com/1-1.css",
        css: "... *css for 1-1.css*",
        childCSS: [
            "http://example.com/1-1-1.css"
        ]
    },
    {
        url: "http://example.com/1-2.css",
        css: "... *css for 1-2.css*",
        childCSS: []
    },
    {
        url: "http://example.com/1-1-1.css",
        css: "... *css for 1-1-1.css*",
        childCSS: [
            "http://example.com/1-1-1-1.css"
        ]
    },
    {
        url: "http://example.com/1-1-1-1.css",
        css: "... *css for 1-1-1-1.css*",
        childCSS: []
    }
];

let dataByUrl = {},
  urlToItem = url => dataByUrl[url];

// index all items by their url
data.forEach(item => {
  dataByUrl[item.url] = item;
});

// now let's update childCSS with the respoective items
data.forEach(item => {
  item.childCSS = item.childCSS.map(urlToItem);
});

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

assuming that your array contains no child before its parent *(wich imo. almost always is the case with such data)*, you can do that in one fell swoop.

```js
let data = [
    {
        url: "http://example.com/1.css",
        css: "... *css for 1.css*",
        childCSS: [
            "http://example.com/1-1.css",
            "http://example.com/1-2.css"
        ]
    },
    {
        url: "http://example.com/1-1.css",
        css: "... *css for 1-1.css*",
        childCSS: [
            "http://example.com/1-1-1.css"
        ]
    },
    {
        url: "http://example.com/1-2.css",
        css: "... *css for 1-2.css*",
        childCSS: []
    },
    {
        url: "http://example.com/1-1-1.css",
        css: "... *css for 1-1-1.css*",
        childCSS: [
            "http://example.com/1-1-1-1.css"
        ]
    },
    {
        url: "http://example.com/1-1-1-1.css",
        css: "... *css for 1-1-1-1.css*",
        childCSS: []
    }
];

let dataByUrl = {},
  urlToItem = url => dataByUrl[url];

for (let i = data.length; i--;) {
  let item = data[i];
  dataByUrl[item.url] = item;
  item.childCSS = item.childCSS.map(urlToItem);
}

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
a.forEach(cssObject=> {
    cssObject.childCSS=_.flatten(cssObject.childCSS.map(reference => 
         a.filter(child => child.url===reference)));
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(a, null, 4));
```

where a is your css array

it returns a structure looking like

```
[
    {
        "url": "http://example.com/1.css",
        "css": "... *css for 1.css*",
        "childCSS": [
            {
                "url": "http://example.com/1-1.css",
                "css": "... *css for 1-1.css*",
                "childCSS": [
                    {
                        "url": "http://example.com/1-1-1.css",
                        "css": "... *css for 1-1-1.css*",
                        "childCSS": [
                            {
                                "url": "http://example.com/1-1-1-1.css",
                                "css": "... *css for 1-1-1-1.css*",
                                "childCSS": []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "url": "http://example.com/1-2.css",
                "css": "... *css for 1-2.css*",
                "childCSS": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "url": "http://example.com/1-1.css",
        "css": "... *css for 1-1.css*",
        "childCSS": [
            {
                "url": "http://example.com/1-1-1.css",
                "css": "... *css for 1-1-1.css*",
                "childCSS": [
                    {
                        "url": "http://example.com/1-1-1-1.css",
                        "css": "... *css for 1-1-1-1.css*",
                        "childCSS": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "url": "http://example.com/1-2.css",
        "css": "... *css for 1-2.css*",
        "childCSS": []
    },
    {
        "url": "http://example.com/1-1-1.css",
        "css": "... *css for 1-1-1.css*",
        "childCSS": [
            {
                "url": "http://example.com/1-1-1-1.css",
                "css": "... *css for 1-1-1-1.css*",
                "childCSS": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "url": "http://example.com/1-1-1-1.css",
        "css": "... *css for 1-1-1-1.css*",
        "childCSS": []
    }
]
```